# Sharepoint 2010 workflow - get url of file by compairing file names of different libraries

Tags: 2010, workflow

I'm using a workflow with "Sharepoint" add-in to convert a InfoPath form to a pdf.

The conversion works fine, and when it convert it to a PDF it puts the PDF in a separate document library.

I'm trying to use the built in email action to compare files names (which are the same) and put the URL to the PDF it converted to with no luck, is it even possible to do this?

In the workflow running off the InfoPath library, created a lookup in the email as follows:

> Field Data to Retrieve DataSource: library that PDF is saved to Field
>   from source:URL Path Return field as: As String
>
> Find the List Item Field: Title Value:Current Item:Title

any help would be great.

Comment: So it seems that I had to create a hyper link and use: [%Variable:ListURL%][%Current Item:Name%].pdf the variable is the url to the list and since it’s the same name it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that I had to create a hyper link and use: [%Variable:ListURL%][%Current Item:Name%].pdf the variable is the url to the list and since it’s the same name it works fine.